# Why real e-mail size is higher than my attachament and text size?

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, size, email-attachments

I have simple code to send e-mail with attachament:

```
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                using (SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"))
                {

                    mail.From = new MailAddress("my_mail@gmail.com");
                    mail.Sender = new MailAddress("my_mail@gmail.com");
                    mail.To.Add("my_mail@gmail.com");
                    mail.Subject = "TEST";
                    mail.Body = "Test body message";

                    //Add attachment
                    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("1568817207ComputationC.part1.rar"); //Size 24MB
                    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my_mail@gmail.com", "password");

                    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                    SmtpServer.Timeout = 0;

                    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                }
            }
```

My attachament has size 24MB + some text = max 25MB

I measured real size of message by "Show original" option in gmail inbox, then i downloaded this message to my hard drive.

Also when i measure how many bites i send when my app is sending e-mail, it shows me 33MB.

So, my question is why real size of this e-mail is 33MB when my attachament + text = max 25MB :D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your email is [MIME encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding) - the binary data is changed from 8-bit data to (normally) 7-bit data, in order to be reliably transmitted between servers. There are a few different encoding schemes, but they will typically add a 33% overhead to the size of your email - so 25Mb of email is actually 32.5Mb of data.

EDIT: [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) has a good explanation of Base64 encoding, usually used when sending emails:

> The number of output bytes per input byte is approximately 4 / 3 (33% overhead) and converges to that value for a large number of bytes. More specifically, given an input of n bytes, the output will be 4[n/3] bytes long, including padding characters.

Answer (score 0):

The email attachment is encoded from binary form (8bit) to ASCII characters only (7bit) using base64 encoding. Thus you don't use all 8 bits in a byte, just 7bits and the email size grows larger.